# Optimize subquery (without using Select inside Where clause)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I am trying to see if there is a way to optimize bottom T-SQL code.

This is how previous co-worker wrote, and I am not sure if there is a better way to write because it has `Select` within the `Where` clause (subquery?).

```
select 
    Employee_Number,    
    DateLoad 
from dbo.table1 as a
where DateLoad = (
    select min(DateLoad)
    from dbo.table2 as b 
    where a.Employee_Number = b.Employee_Number
)
```

Comment: SQL is declarative. A piece of SQL text is not optimal or sub optimal - this only happens after it is converted to an execution plan. SQL Server can often convert this sort of thing into a join in the execution plan. In the case that you were referencing the same table it can even use the ["segment top"](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.html) optimisation to further simplify things

Comment: e.g. Here your original query text ends up with a merge join https://dbfiddle.uk/LjFcTk03

Comment: Are there any indexes on `table2` ?

Comment: @Sean Yes there is an index on table2, actually on both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still uses a nested SELECT, but not in the WHERE clause and should run faster:

```
SELECT Employee_Number, DateLoad
FROM (
    select a.Employee_number, a.DateLoad
       , row_number() over (partition by a.Employee_Number
                            order by b.DateLoad) rn
    from Table1 A
    inner join Table2 B on B.Employee_Number = A.Employee_Number 
        and a.DateLoad = b.DateLoad
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Depending on the data there might also be a way to do this using GROUP BY, without any nesting:

```
SELECT A.Employee_Number, Min(B.DateLoad) DateLoad
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON B.Employee_Number = A.Employee_Number 
    AND a.DateLoad = b.DateLoad
GROUP BY A.Employee_Number
```

But I'm not 100% certain this will be functionally equivalent to the original. You'll want to check carefully to be sure it works reliably on your data.

The main thing to understand is a JOIN is almost always faster than a correlated nested SELECT ("correlated" mean "per row" in this context), and not by just a little. The only exception I'm aware of is using an EXISTS() predicate instead of an exclusion join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```sql
/* Load Data*/
--Solution Query:
select 
    a.Employee_Number,
    b.DateLoad
FROM
    dbo.table1 AS a
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT MIN(b1.DateLoad) DateLoad FROM dbo.table2 AS b1 WHERE b1.Employee_Number = a.Employee_Number HAVING MIN(b1.DateLoad) = a.DateLoad) AS b
```

And to setup the sample in SQLLocalDb (2022) I used the following, taking some liberties in some of the hypothetical schema:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'so_75678891')
    CREATE DATABASE so_75678891
GO
    USE so_75678891 
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.table1
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1 (Employee_Number VARCHAR(10), DateLoad DATETIMEOFFSET(0),SomeTable1Info VARCHAR(100), SomeTable1JSON NVARCHAR(MAX))

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.table2
CREATE TABLE dbo.table2 (Employee_Number VARCHAR(10), SomeTable2Info VARCHAR(100), DateLoad DATETIMEOFFSET(0))

/*One example of indexes:*/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX t2_employee_plusdate ON dbo.table2 (Employee_Number) INCLUDE (DateLoad)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX t1_employee_date ON dbo.table1 (Employee_Number,DateLoad) INCLUDE(SomeTable1Info)
GO

/* Load Data*/
```

I first excluded the `HAVING` clause and ended up with the exact same query plan as the OP, but (imo) I think this was still a more *maintainable* style of query if thinking about a "better way to write".

My personal preference (if appropriate):

```sql
select 
    a.Employee_Number,
    b.DateLoad
FROM
    dbo.table1 AS a
    CROSS APPLY dbo.MinT2DateMatch(a.Employee_Number,a.DateLoad) AS b
```

Either way, leaves your `WHERE` clause free to define specific logic to the needs of *this* query such as matching input parameters or filtering based on the current date, and leaves logic to get data *from* the database in the `FROM` clause (of all places...)